# mongodb atlas connection issues with ssl

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I've created a cluster using mongodb atlas. But, I couldn't connect to that using local mongo shell.

When I use the below connection string, it says --ssl unrecognized.

```
Harshavardhans-MacBook-Pro:bin harshavmb$ mongo "mongodb://m123-rs1-shard-00-00-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-01-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-02-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=m123-rs1-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username mongoadmin --password *****
```

**Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--ssl'
try 'mongo --help' for more information**

If I remove `--ssl` and try, I see the below o/p.

```
Harshavardhans-MacBook-Pro:bin harshavmb$ mongo "mongodb://m123-rs1-shard-00-00-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-01-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-02-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=m123-rs1-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --username mongoadmin --password ****
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: mongodb://m123-rs1-shard-00-00-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-01-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-02-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=m123-rs1-shard-0
2017-03-18T14:19:00.820+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for m123-rs1-shard-0/m123-rs1-shard-00-00-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-01-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-02-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:00.820+0530 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
2017-03-18T14:19:06.255+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() timeout  35.167.185.140:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:06.258+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_TIMEOUT] server [35.167.185.140:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:07.040+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.162.95.185:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:07.040+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.162.95.185:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:07.757+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.162.83.174:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:07.757+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.162.83.174:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:07.757+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set m123-rs1-shard-0
2017-03-18T14:19:08.985+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.162.95.185:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:08.985+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.162.95.185:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:09.702+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.162.83.174:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:09.702+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.162.83.174:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:10.419+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.167.185.140:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:10.419+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.167.185.140:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:10.419+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set m123-rs1-shard-0
2017-03-18T14:19:11.648+0530 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.162.95.185:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:11.648+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.167.185.140:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:11.648+0530 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.162.95.185:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:11.648+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.167.185.140:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:12.364+0530 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.162.83.174:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:12.365+0530 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.162.83.174:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:12.365+0530 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] No primary detected for set m123-rs1-shard-0
2017-03-18T14:19:14.731+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.162.83.174:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:14.731+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.162.83.174:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:14.731+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set m123-rs1-shard-0
2017-03-18T14:19:15.845+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.162.95.185:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:15.845+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.162.95.185:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:16.563+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.167.185.140:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:16.563+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.167.185.140:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:17.176+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() errno:54 Connection reset by peer 35.162.83.174:27017
2017-03-18T14:19:17.177+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [35.162.83.174:27017] 
2017-03-18T14:19:17.177+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set m123-rs1-shard-0
2017-03-18T14:19:17.181+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: connect failed to replica set m123-rs1-shard-0/m123-rs1-shard-00-00-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-01-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017,m123-rs1-shard-00-02-wn1jr.mongodb.net:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:223:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Interestingly, I was able to connect to the cluster with java driver. Only shell has this problem.

Have googled a lot to find fix this ssl issue, but couldn't find any helpful link.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had copied Mongo `3.2` binaries to `/usr/local/bin` directory, so this wasn't allowing newer version of mongo binaries (3.4). So, eventually I had to remove the binaries from `/usr/local/bin` directory and paste the binaries of `3.4` and this fixed the ssl issue.

Answer (score 1):

> **Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--ssl' try 'mongo --help' for more information**

MongoDB Atlas [requires SSL/TLS](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/faq/#can-i-disable-ssl-tls-on-my-deployment) for all connections. This command-line error indicates your version of the `mongo` shell does not include SSL/TLS support.

Depending on your preference, you can install an appropriate `mongo` shell version using:

- [Homebrew](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#install-the-mongodb-binaries-with-tls-ssl-support): `brew install mongodb --with-openssl`.
- [MongoDB Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center).  Note: the default should be to download binaries w/ SSL support, but there are non-SSL downloads available in the dropdown list as well.

It's generally better to install a packaged version (eg. Homebrew) as this simplifies the process of managing the `mongod` service and updating to new releases. The binary downloads may be more relevant if you want to run multiple versions of MongoDB or keep files isolated to a specific directory, but do not include conveniences like a service wrapper or default config file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the issue. I had copied Mongo 3.2 binaries to /usr/local/bin directory, so this wasn't allowing newer version of mongo binaries (3.4). So, eventually I had to remove the binaries from /usr/local/bin directory and paste the binaries of 3.4 and this fixed the ssl issue.

Thanks again for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have mongodb with SSL/TSL because MongoDB Atlas needs it for  all connections.

You can get by running following command.

```
brew install mongodb --with-openssl
```

And upgrade your mongodb to 3.4.4.

```
brew upgrade mongodb
```

Then try connecting to mongo cloud via mongo shell.

Answer (score 1):

Recently MongoDb Atlas switched their certificates from Digicert to LetsEncrypt (Feb 2020), and it may have issues for certificate stores that don't have the LetsEncrypt ones it in.

A temporary bypass is to include `sslVerifyCertificate=false` on the end of a connection string.  But the solution is to update your OS or driver libraries to have a version that includes the LetsEncrypt certificates.

Comment: And in spark.read.format("mongo").... option("sslVerifyCertificate", "false").load